# How can I "mimic" a one to many relationship with react firebase cloud?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to make a small project using react js in which one can sign up/ sign in and then make a post on the web app. I have made the authentication component, but I have trouble displaying only the posts that were made by the logged user. (currently, it shows all posts from the database)
My current db is like this:
user
    -email
    -displayName
post
    -text
    -image
My current approach was the following, where db is:

```
db = firebaseApp.firestore();
```

for the posts:

```
db.collection("posts").add({
                text: message,
                image: media
            });
```

and for the users:

```
db.collection("users").add({
         email: email
    });
```

I was thinking of changing the db structure, like so:
user
    -email
    -displayName
    -text1
    -image1
    ...
However, it is not possible to dynamically set the keys' names, and I don't know how I can store the post and then access it via code.

Answer (score 1):

You can try structure your database like this

```
user
   email
   displayName

post
   creator
   text
   image
```

The `creator` field contain user's ID that is the owner of the post. When you want to fetch only the post created by that user, you can use `where` to filter that out. Here is the reference https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries